# Updating field value on MySQL table after 24 hours automatically

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores some sensitive information but I would like that information to change to NULL when it exceeds 24 hours. How can I do that? I have a column named "last_updated" and stores value like this "2014-02-26 16:25:58".

How can I compare the last_updated value with the current time and if it exceeds 24 hours, the other field will change to "NULL".

Should I put something like `UPDATE table SET info=NULL WHERE last_updated > 24hour?` I don't know how to compare the last_updated when its 24 hours later.

or is there a function inside MySQL to check automatically without running the query using phpmyadmin?

Comment: This seems like a false choice from a security standpoint.  If the data is that sensitive perhaps it should be encrypted for storage and not rely on some expiry concept.

Comment: its already encrypted into hash key, but I still want to remove the data from my table... I just want to keep the data for 24 hours

Comment: Have you tried to write a script to do this?

Comment: yea, using this UPDATE table SET info=NULL WHERE last_updated > 24hour as above... but I don't know the command to compare the last_updated field.. and I also don't know if there is any other better solution to do this. That's why I'm asking for better recommendations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a scheduled job that resets the data.  Of course, the time span would be 24-48 hours to the change, if you run the job only once per day.

There is another option.  That is to do all the data access via views.  Then the view could say:

```
create view v_table as
    select (case when last_updated > now() - interval 1 day then col1 end) as col1,
           . . .
    from table;
```

Then, you can then update the data at your leisure -- if you still find that necessary.  Access to the data won't be dependent on a job and job scheduler.  If all accesses to the data are through the view, then after 24 hours, the data will appear as `NULL`.

Comment: Actually I don't quite understand your solution but this line" last_updated > now() - interval 1 day" I think it helps me on the query to compare the "last_updated" field. Thanks.